# Wget http auth incorrect username and password combination

Tags: http, sharepoint, web, wget

I'm at a total loss as to why I'm getting Authorization failed messages when I try to perform basic HTTP auth using wget on an internal webpage.

I've been using this wget command to pull a csv file from an internal webpage for around 4 months on a daily basis without issues.

```
wget --user username --password "password" http://internalwebsite.domain.com/data.csv
```

The site is not SSL and does prompt for credentials when visiting it with a web browser. I've verified that the credentials I am using in the call work in a browser to download the CSV.

I've tried modifying the wget command by adding the following additional flags:

```
--auth-no-challenge
```

I also changed the --username to --http-user and the password to --http-passwd but those options do not work either.

When I attempt the connection with wget I get a 401 Unauthorized Authorization failed message.

The site is sharepoint,and unless something recently changed this month with IIS that disables calls from wget, I cannot figure out for the life of me what changed...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this issue by switching my command to cURL...not exactly sure why it is working when wget does not.

Here's my code:

```
curl -o /path/to/file/filename.csv --anyauth --user "username:password" http://domain.com/filename.csv
```